# Image & Css not working using codeigniter 3 dompdf

Tags: css, image, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, dompdf

I am using *codeigniter 3* and *dompdf* to convert a html view to pdf. I can successfully convert the html to pdf, but no proper style is being applied.
All required css files have been included as a customized design in the view file.

What else do I need to do in order to include the css styles and image properly?

here is the controller:

```
public function get_pdf_test($id)
  {
    //  print_r($_REQUEST);
    //   die;
      $data['incidents'] = $this->incidents_model->getById($id);
      $data['incidents_history'] = $this->incidents_model->getById_history($id); 
      $data['company_name'] = $this->incidents_model->getAllCompanyName();
     
      generate_pdf("admin/incidents/incidentsView.pdf", "admin/incidents/incidentsView.php", $data);
    
      }
```

incident_model.php

```
     function getById($id) 
    {
  
       return $this->db->get_where('incidents',array('id'=>$id))->row();
    }
 function getById_history($id)
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT incidents_id FROM incidents WHERE id = $id");
        $get_row = $query->row();
        $incident_id = $get_row->incidents_id;
        
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where(array('incidents.incidents_id'=>$incident_id));
        $this->db->join('incident_status', 'incidents.id = incident_status.incident_id');
        return $this->db->get('incidents')->result(); 
    } 
function getAllCompanyName()
    {
      $query = $this->db->get('company_details');
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT company_name FROM company_details where delete_flag =0');
      return $query->result();
    }
```

Pdf.php file in library:

```
 <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 *
 * Convert HTML to PDF in CodeIgniter applications.
 *
 * @package            CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage        Libraries
 * @category        Libraries
 * @author            Hostmystory
 * @link            https://www.hostmystory.com
 */

// Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class Pdf
{
    public function __construct(){   
        // require_once autoloader 
        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
        $pdf = new DOMPDF();
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->dompdf = $pdf;

    }
}
?>
```

new_helper.php in helper:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
// generate pdf
function generate_pdf($name, $tpl, $data)
{
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $data['data'] = $data;
    $ci->load->view($tpl, $data);
    // Get output html
    $html = $ci->output->get_output();
// add external css library
    $html .= '<link href="' . base_url() . 'assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">';

    // Load pdf library
    $ci->load->library('pdf');
    $ci->dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    // setup size
    $ci->dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $ci->dompdf->render();
    // Output  PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview)
    $ci->dompdf->stream($name, array("Attachment" => 0));
}
?>
```

here is the out put of dompdf :

[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new solution, please let me know, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question

> Image & Css not working using codeigniter 3 dompdf

and following your example, I installed *CI 3.11.1* and *Dompdf 1.0.2* and came up with 2 solutions

**Solution 1 - setting dompdf option:**

in your library load dompdf with option enable_remote set to true:

```
$pdf = new Dompdf(array('enable_remote' => true));
```

**Image**

in your html use base_url() to create an absolute image path, e.g.:

```
<img src="<?=base_url('assets/_img/logo.png')?>" />
```

**CSS**

your approach should work now.

---

**Solution 2 - embedding:**

**Image**: another way to display images is to embed images, using the [data URI scheme](http://data:image%20link:%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)
and [base64_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php):

To do so, you must use a `absolute/path/to/your_image`, which CI easily enables with its [base_url()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#base_url) function

```
$imgpath=base_url('assets/_img/logo.png');
$ext= pathinfo($imgpath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($imgpath);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $ext. ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

**Stylesheet**: To add a css style sheet,  you embed the style sheet between a `<style></style>` element, again getting it with an absolute path:

```
$path = base_url('assets/_css/dompdf.css');
$data = file_get_contents($path);
//$css = '<link type="text/css" href="'.$data.'" rel="stylesheet" />';  // couldn’t get this to work
$css="<style>$data</style>";
```

this is the stylesheet I used:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.red{
    color:red; 
    width:100%; 
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size:48px;
}
img{
    width:300px; 
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

So finally a possible html could look like this:

```
$html='<div class="red">Hello world!</div><img src="'.$base64.'"/><div>unformated text</div>';
```

To create the pdf, we load the library and send `$css` and `$html` to build it:

```
$this->load->library('pdf');
$this->dompdf->loadHtml($css.$html);
$this->dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$this->dompdf->render();
$this->dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));
```

Possible Output:

[image]

**note**: *Dompdf 1.0.1* is basically limited to css2 standard (with a few few css3 exceptions), see: [Dompdf Features](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#features)